# React-Mobx 2020. inject hooks and useObserver

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, mobx, mobx-react

When I get the data (**view**) from **useStore**, I have to write all the way to this (**view: myStore.menu.view**) and still wrap it all in **useObserver**. Is there a way to shorten the code, but still keep the logic the same? I use **Mobx** and **React Hooks**.

Thanks in advance!

```
function useBasketStore() {
  const { myStore } = useStore(['exampleStore']);

  return useObserver(() => ({
    view: myStore.menu?.view,
  }));
}

const BasketScreen = () => {
  const { view } = useBasketStore();
......
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think no way. Only the case if your component wrapped by observer. Then you can just use data:

```js
function useBasketStore() {
  const { myStore } = useStore(['exampleStore']);

  return {
    view: myStore.menu?.view,
  };
}

const BasketScreen = () => {
  const { view } = useBasketStore();
......
}

export default observer(BasketScreen)
```

Comment: I thought maybe there is a newer way. In any case, thanks a lot for the information!